# Portable C Compiler (pcc) with GTK+ in Code::Blocks

Tags: gtk, codeblocks

I had some problems when trying to compile a GTK+ program with Portable C Compiler (pcc) using Code::Blocks in Windows. When I tried to build the default GTK+ project in Code::Blocks, I get these errors:

`-------------- Build: Debug in cb-temp2 ---------------`

Compiling: main.c
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gutils.h, line 423: parameter 'glib_major_version' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gutils.h, line 424: function declaration in bad context
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gutils.h, line 424: parameter '__declspec' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gutils.h, line 424: parse error
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gutils.h, line 425: redeclaration of __declspec
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gutils.h, line 425: parameter 'glib_micro_version' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gutils.h, line 426: function declaration in bad context
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gutils.h, line 426: parameter '__declspec' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gutils.h, line 426: parse error
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gutils.h, line 427: redeclaration of __declspec
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gutils.h, line 427: parameter 'glib_binary_age' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gutils.h, line 431: parameter 'glib_check_version' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gatomic.h, line 42: parameter 'g_atomic_int_exchange_and_add' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gatomic.h, line 44: parameter 'g_atomic_int_add' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gatomic.h, line 47: parameter 'g_atomic_int_compare_and_exchange' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gatomic.h, line 50: parameter 'g_atomic_pointer_compare_and_exchange' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gatomic.h, line 52: parameter 'g_atomic_int_get' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gatomic.h, line 54: parameter 'g_atomic_int_set' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gatomic.h, line 55: parameter 'g_atomic_pointer_get' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gatomic.h, line 57: parameter 'g_atomic_pointer_set' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h, line 44: parameter 'g_thread_error_quark' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h, line 50: parameter 'GThreadError' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h, line 52: parameter 'GThreadFunc' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h, line 60: parameter 'GThreadPriority' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h, line 62: parameter 'GThread' not defined
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h, line 66: parse error
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h, line 66: invalid function definition
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h, line 66: function illegal in structure or union
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h, line 66: invalid function definition
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h, line 66: function illegal in structure or union
C:\CMPITG\gtk\include\glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h, line 67: cannot recover from earlier errors: goodbye!
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings

I have successfully compiled the same project with gcc and now I'm still not able to compile it with pcc. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Let them know at the PCC project.  Give them as much information as you can.

Comment: God! You're right! I should have done that a time ago. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell, but I think you have an open parenthesis or curly brace before your `#include <gtk/gtk.h>`.

Comment: Of course not, I tried to use both double-quote and "<" & ">" pair but it's no use. I got no problems with when compiling with gcc. Maybe those errors are due to pcc's bugs?